# Angular - Trouble with ng-change

Tags: angularjs

I am still a little new to Angular, and I am having trouble setting the default select option, if that option is the only one in the array. What happens specifically is that the select does default, however, the shipping cost is not being calculated. It only calculates if the user chooses it from the drop down. I think the issue may be because with the ng-change on the select element, but I am not sure.

In my HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="updateShipper()" name="shipMethod"
ng-model="currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName"
ng-show="user.ShipMethod.ShipperSelectionType == 'UserDropDown'"
ng-options="shipper.Name as (shipper.Name + ' ' + (shipper.ShippingRate.Price | currency | xlat)) for shipper in shippers"
ng-required="!currentOrder.IsMultipleShip() && user.ShipMethod != null" >
<option value=""></option>
```

In my controller:

```
    scope.$watch('shippers', function(val) {
            if(angular.isDefined(val)){
                $timeout(function() {
                    if(val.length === 1){
                        scope.currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName = val[0].Name;
                    }
                }, 0); 
            }
        });



    $scope.updateShipper = function(li) {
            $scope.shippingUpdatingIndicator = true;
            $scope.shippingFetchIndicator = true;
            if (!li) { // at the order level
                angular.forEach($scope.shippers, function(s) {
                    if (s.Name == $scope.currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName)
                        $scope.currentOrder.Shipper = s;
                });

                angular.forEach($scope.currentOrder.LineItems, function(item) {
                    item.ShipperName = $scope.currentOrder.Shipper ? $scope.currentOrder.Shipper.Name : null;
                    item.ShipperID = $scope.currentOrder.Shipper ? $scope.currentOrder.Shipper.ID : null;
                });

                saveChanges(function() {
                    $scope.shippingUpdatingIndicator = false;
                    $scope.shippingFetchIndicator = false;
                });
            }
            else { // at the lineitem level for multiple shipping
                angular.forEach($scope.shippers, function(s) {
                    if (s.Name == li.ShipperName)
                        li.Shipper = s;
                });
                li.ShipperName = li.Shipper.Name;
                li.ShipperID = li.Shipper.ID;
                saveChanges(function() {
                    $scope.shippingUpdatingIndicator = false;
                    $scope.shippingFetchIndicator = false;
                });
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-init="updateShipper()"`. Then set the initial value of your model in the controller like `$scope.currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName = 0(or whatever)`.

Comment: I did try that, but no luck. Thank you for your response.